# Custom feature while checkout. Can I add this?

Tags: checkout, custom, reward-points

I am going to start an e-commerce website on this platform, but just needed some info on it.

Like suppose the Cart value of the buyer is Rs.997. I want to add a feature that allows user to pay Rs.1000 and let him choose either of the two options from below:

1. Donate the Rs.3 for charity or some social work
2. Convert that Rs.3 to coins/points that are added to his/her account.

This will help in COD deliveries.

Can this be done in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Donate the Rs.3 for charity or some social work

Using a custom totals model, yes.

> 2. Convert that Rs.3 to coins/points that are added to his/her account.

Without much further specification, this can be done as well, but of course will require additional custom programming beyond the custom totals model.